# Itunes connect localization

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store-connect, itunes, itunes-store

I submitted my app to review with English(US) as primary language and I made a Danish localization with separate screenshots, description, keywords and such. After my app was approved and released to appstore the danish localization just was not there. I am using danish appstore on my iphone and the whole page was in English. Also when I view the app in the web browser in US appsotre and also DK appsotre, both are in english. I also localized the app itself to English and Danish.

Anyone had a similar problem ? I have an older app on the appstore which is also localized and I have not had this issue with that one.

Answer (score 2):

I have settings localized on ItunesConnect and everything works.

Please check your steps as below:

1. ItunesConnect >> Your App >> App Information: your app name in localization
2. ItunesConnect >> Your App >> Latest app version: your desc, screenshoot, keywords in localization
3. To check localized in Denmark (Danish): https://itunes.apple.com/dk/app/idYourappID

Comment: So everything is localized beside the name which is the same in English as well as danish but when i go to  https://itunes.apple.com/dk/app/idYourappID i get english for dasnish appstore as well.

Comment: You means you setting the app name in Danish same like English. Therefore your app name in Danish store still English.
Please make app name in Danish by yourself. Appstore don't auto translate to Danish for you.

Comment: I did select danish as my primary language and that did the trick